# Is it possible to make a subatomic gap?

Tags: atomic-physics

This was a bit hard to google due to lack of a distinct search term. What I mean is that while we can't make a physical construct that's thinner than one atom, I thought it might be possible to make a gap between two objects that is too small for any atom to pass through (assuming hydrogen since it's the smallest).

Here's a crude unicode diagram:

[image: Subatomic gap]

Or alternatively, some sort of array of barriers aligned such that there's a subatomic width passage through them, like this:

[image: Subatomic path]

And what about even smaller particles? Could we use this to craft even smaller electron beam pinhole apertures?

I also imagine the answers might be different in theory and in practice.

Comment: Your imagery of rigid barriers goes against the grain of quantum mechanics which describes small distance phenomena. But, still, neutrinos are so "thin" that easily slip in between atoms, most of the time, as per your picture.

Comment: Yeah, please forgive the crude images, and imagine the barriers as part of some larger construct. I'll try to come up with something better if the question gets a bit more traction.

But are you saying that if one were to bring two objects that close together, then small distance phenomena would ensure that the gap would either be too wide or close completely? Maybe you could elaborate in a full answer?

Comment: A full answer requires quantum mechanics, and quantum mechanics needs a course, cannot be contained in an answer here. Look at the probable locations of an electron in the hydrogen atom, which would define its    probable size in a given instant of time  here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics

Comment: Helium is the smallest atom, not hydrogen (which is only the lightest). But atoms don't have a well-defined size either; they have fuzzy edges. (And "helium is the smallest" really means "helium's influence/electron density falls off fastest with distance".)

Comment: @HTNW  the same **quantum mechanical** indeterminacy of position exists for all atoms, helium included.